# App should be startable by its name in the command line

Tags: command-line, unity-dash

I already managed to create a .desktop file, moved it to /usr/share/applications, and can start my app from the dash where the icon appears.
The app is started by the command "python3 /path/to/script" still. 
I thought now as I have the starter in the applications folder it would be sufficient to type its name into the command line (alt+f2) and it would start, but it says the command is unknown.

Where in the system do I have to place a file to let the system know that the app-name is a command? Just like typing "firefox" and firefox starts...

Answer (score 2):

- Put it in the path or alter the path. You can run `echo $PATH` to see your path. If this is just for one user, `~/bin/` is a suitable location. Otherwise, move the file to `/usr/local/bin/`. You'll need to do that as root.
- In order for it to be directly executable (without asking Python to run it explicitly):

  - It needs to be executable: `chmod +x filename`
  - It needs a shebang at the beginning of a file: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`
  - You should probably rename it so it doesn't have .py on the end

The alternative for this is you just create a launcher shell script that runs `python /path/to/script.py`. This would save you having to move your file somewhere special but the same rules apply. It needs would need to be set executable, be in your path and start with a `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` shebang.

Comment: By "it", you mean the python script and not the .desktop-file, right? And I don't understand what you mean by "put it in the path", which path? The path filled in the exec-part of the .desktop-file already leads to the script. The script itself has the shebang already. Going to test without the .py on the end..

Comment: ah and by the way, shouldn't 3rd party apps not be installed to /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either place the script within your $PATH or add the path where the script is located to your $PATH (I'd recommend the first). To avoid having to manually choose the interpreter to invoke, you should include a shebang line at the top of your script like `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and make the script executable with `chmod a+x name_of_script`. You can then remove the .py extension and call it by its name within the terminal.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. The shebang was there and I was wondering why I needed to explicitly call "python3". I will try the other 2 points, though I thought I've made it executable... Just a question about "name_of_script": Is it only the name or the absolute path?

Comment: `name_of_script` will be the absolute path. You should explicitly call `python3` because `python` may be a symlink to a python2.x version.